# Setting cursor for the gap in between controls

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse-cursor

I have statically added few .cur files to the executable. I can get them well;

```
wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(151)); //before registering window class
HCURSOR cursn=LoadCursor(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(151));
HCURSOR cibeam=LoadCursor(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(152));
```

Then I use this method I've found after some search;

```
SetClassLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hwnd,4),GCLP_HCURSOR,LONG_PTR(cursn)); //on a button
SetClassLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hwnd,21),GCLP_HCURSOR,LONG_PTR(cibeam)); //on an edit box
```

Now the custom cursors are working fine. But there's an issue. When the cursor is pointing the gap between controls, it turns to the default IDC_ARROW [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVfgb.jpg) How can I make these gaps use `cursn`?

Comment: Have you tried SetClassLongPtr(hwnd,GCLP_HCURSOR,LONG_PTR(cursn))

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It is non-standard (and counter-intuitive) behaviour.

Comment: @dkackman Yes, I've tried `SetClassLongPtr(hwnd,GCLP_HCURSOR,LONG_PTR(cursn));` before but I think it only does the very same thing as `wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(151));` does, nothing more.

Comment: @PaulSanders I covered everywhere with some cursor but gaps still remain with the default `IDC_ARROW`. It doesn't look nice

Comment: The cursor shape is determined by the window class entry to which the window underneath the cursor position belongs, unless that window's window procedure overrides this setting by handling the [WM_SETCURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor) message. This is documented behavior: [Setting the Cursor Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/setting-the-cursor-image).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, with your help I did what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that "the gaps" between controls are called `nonclient area` and setting cursor like this;

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    if(LOWORD(lParam)!=HTCLIENT) //the opposite of the example documented on MSDN
    {
        SetCursor(cursn);
        return 1;
    }
    break;
}
```

It may be nonstandard and disapproved but it still looks nicer.